# Rhomobile - load_offline_data issue

Tags: rhomobile

I am facing issue with load_offline_data when used to load seed data from .txt files

My code will look like this :

```
> def initialize
>     Rho::RHO.load_all_sources()
>     products = Product.find(:all)
>     Rho::RhoUtils.load_offline_data(['products'], 'db')   end
```

In db/fixtures/products.txt

```
source_name|attrib|object|value
Product|name|1|product 1| Product|order_id|1|1|

Product|name|2|product 2|
Product|order_id|2|2|
```

I am getting error  like this :

**Application initialize failed: #source_id' for nil:NilClass>;Trace: lib/rho/rhoutils.rb:71:inblock (3 levels) in load_offline_data'**

Could any one help me..

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Sri, I had to manually require 'rho/rhoutils'.

To avoid the source_id error, I had to call Rhom::Rhom.database_full_reset(true, true).  Since this would reset the database every time the application initialized, I included a guard checking that my trees table was already populated.

```
require 'rho/rhoapplication'
require 'rho/rhoutils'

class AppApplication < Rho::RhoApplication
  def initialize
    # Tab items are loaded left->right, @tabs[0] is leftmost tab in the tab-bar
    # Super must be called *after* settings @tabs!
    @tabs = nil
    #To remove default toolbar uncomment next line:
    #@@toolbar = nil
    super

    if Tree.find_all.empty?
      Rhom::Rhom.database_full_reset(true, true)
      Rho::RhoUtils.load_offline_data(['object_values'], '')
    else
      puts "*"*80
      puts "ALL GOOD"*5
      puts "*"*80
    end

    # Uncomment to set sync notification callback to /app/Settings/sync_notify.
    # SyncEngine::set_objectnotify_url("/app/Settings/sync_notify")
    # SyncEngine.set_notification(-1, "/app/Settings/sync_notify", '')
  end
end
```